# Algorithm of checking a grammar against another grammar in ll(1)

Tags: java, parsing, computer-science, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I need an algorithm that checks if the language of G1 is a subset of G2's language or not. (Assume G1 and G2 are two LL(1) grammars with identical alphabets whose production rules are either of the form  A-->aB  or  A-->a  , and "a" is a non-epsilon. I have a parsing algorithms that  checking a grammar against a string but not checks against another language. Is there anyone who has a solution.

Comment: Is it homework? Anyway there is cs.stackexchange.com in case answers here are sparse.

Comment: Generally, we check a grammar against an input string but the problem is, in this part we have 2 different grammar which may have a lot of production rules.So I think there should be a method or algorithm which I can use for example in java programming language.

Comment: I know that it can be solved using two stacks, such that it checks if the FIRST of the string on top of the stack is a subset of the other one. Any recommended java code?

Answer (score 1):

Your grammars look like they're right regular.  So the algorithm is to convert the grammars to NFAs. This is a trivial 1-1 mapping. Then convert the NFAs into DFAs with the subset construction. Call these A and B. It's easy to analyze them to determine L(A) subset? L(B). For example, since there are well known efficient algorithms for determining L(A) ==? L(B) and constructing a new machine I(A,B) that accepts L(A) intersection L(B), just compute

```
( L(I(A,B)) ==? L(A) )  or  ( L(I(A,B)) ==? L(B) )
```